# Program crashes when I give printf a pointer to a char array

Tags: c

When I try to run the following code I get a seg fault. I've tried running it through gdb, and I understand that the error is occurring as part of calling `printf`, but I'm lost as to why exactly it isn't working.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char c[5] = "Test";
  char *type = NULL;

  type = &c[0];
  printf("%s\n", *type);
}
```

If I replace `printf("%s\n", *type);` 
with `printf("%s\n", c);` I get "Test" printed as I expected. Why doesn't it work with a pointer to the char array?

Comment: I just would like to nitpick:  "C" did not crash because C is not a program.  Your compiler did not crash.  ***You used C to write a program that crashes.***

Comment: You are correct David. I know what I meant to say, and so do you, obviously, but it is important to be precise when discussing these sorts of things.

Comment: Change your `%s` to `%c` to see the `c[0]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're passing a plain `char` and `printf` is trying to dereference it. Try this instead:

```
printf("%s\n", type);
              ^
```

If you pass `*type` it's like telling `printf` "I've got a string at location T".

Also `type = &c[0]` is kind of misleading. Why don't you just:

```
type = c;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Just when I thought I was getting the hang of pointers, I realize that I need to review them a little more.

Answer (score 5):

Don't dereference `type`. It must remain a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the dereferencing of `type` in your `printf`.